# What are "switched files" with regard to SVN/IntelliJ?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, intellij-idea

I have an existing Maven project, which I used to create a new IntelliJ project (the "Import project from external model" option). I changed a few files and committed them.

Then I realized I was on the wrong branch (let's call it `wrong`). I exited IDEA, used Tortoise SVN to switch to the correct branch (let's call it `right`), and then re-opened IDEA. Everything seems fine, *except* that I now have a group in the Local tab of the Changes window called "Switched Files." This "Switched Files" has a subgroup called "branches/wrong" which appears to contain ALL the files in the entire repository! These files do not differ from the ones checked into `right`, and most of them do not differ from the ones in `wrong`, either. Yet here they are in my Changes window.

Moreover, these files do not show up in a Tortoise "Commit" window, but they *do* show up in a Tortoise "Check for modifications" window. But again, these files have not been modified, nor have any of their properties been modified, so far as I can tell.

What are "Switched Files" and how do I simply revert *everything* to the `right` branch?

Comment: I haven't played with a switch command in svn, but generally when something like that happen, I just do clean checkout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently this is just a Subversion thing. I was unaware of the concept of "switched" files. You can tell if some of your files are switched by using the command line:

```
$ svn st
    S  file1.txt
    S  file2.txt
```

The "switched" files will be marked with an 'S'. If you execute `svn info` on one of these files, you will see that the URL listed does not match the URL of your current branch. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269996/svn-what-does-the-status-switched-relative-to-its-parent-mean) for more info.

I still don't know what it means really, or how it got into that state just by doing "Tortoise -> Switch...", but I do know how to fix it:

```
$ svn switch URL
```

Where `URL` is the svn:// URL of the branch that you want to switch to. That should recursively scan all files and put them firmly on the "right" branch.

Comment: Any way to do this in idea?

Comment: regarding how it got to this state, in my case I think it happened when the switching was interrupted by a network problem

Answer (score 7):

I just had a similar issue where after switching branches, one file was marked as "switched" for some reason.

I was able to fix this through IDEA by making sure I didn't any local changes, switching back to the "wrong" branch, then again switching to the "right" branch.

Note that I'm using IDEA to switch, rather than Tortoise.

Comment: For me switching to a third branch and back also worked. (Might be desirable if that branch is more similar).